# Organizing data in a class

Tags: c#

I have a question regarding the way I'm storing data in my application, keep in mind I'm not too experienced with C#. So, I am grabbing data from a file and able to print it all out using a foreach loops

```
try
{
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(htmlDoc);
    var i = 0;
    foreach (HtmlNode row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr"))
    {
        if (i <= 6) { Console.Write("[Type1]"); }
        if (i >= 7 && i <= 12) { Console.Write("[Type2 i + " : "); }
        if (i >= 13 && i <= 23) { Console.Write("[Type3] i + " : "); }
        if (i >= 24 && i <= 33) { Console.Write("[Type4]" + i + " : "); }
        if (i >= 34 && i <= 39) { Console.Write("[Type5]" + i + " : "); }
        if (i > 38 || i < 1) { Console.Write("Error LTZ or GTV"); }
        Console.Write(row.Elements("td").First().InnerText);
        Console.Write(" - ");
        Console.WriteLine(row.Elements("td").Last().InnerText);
        i++;
    }

}
```

This part works fine, it prints them all out with the appropriate tag in front of the data. What I am trying to accomplish is instead of printing the data out I want to store it in my class. I have it modeled like this currently

```
public class House
{
    //Downstairs
    public int DBedrooms {get; set; }
    public int DKitchens {get; set; }
    public int DLiving { get; set; }
    //upstairs
    public int UBedrooms { get; set; }
    public int UKitchens { get; set; }
    public int ULiving { get; set; }
    //Neighborhood
    public string NSchool { get; set; }
    public int NSchoolDist { get; set; }
    public int NCrime { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

there's about 40 public ints in the class currently and I'm just wondering what a better way to store the data would be!

Comment: Sounds like you have it spot on, unless you can model your data differently.

Comment: Do you think using nested classes would be okay to do here? I just feel like I have a List<>() declared as a class or something, but it's' the only way i could think of to do it :S What would be a more effective way to model this, if any at all?

Comment: @Ian Sure, you could have `House` as an abstract base class with `downstairs`, `upstairs`, and `neighborhood` as child classes.

Comment: You could do a slightly more object oriented approach to slim down your House class by adding object parameters instead of the individual int and possible reuse them depending on your application. Example: `class House { public Bedroom thisbedroom;...}` `class Bedroom { public string owner; public int residents;` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every structure that can have duplicates should have their own class instead of just declaring a lot of properties, and I personally like storing such structures in a list. you would also want to add them to the list in the right order so you don't mistake the upstairs for the downstairs.

For the ability to have many floors in a house i would organize like so:

```
public class Floor {
    public int DBedrooms {get; set; }
    public int DKitchens {get; set; }
    public int DLiving { get; set; } 
}

public class House {
    public List<Floor> Floors{get;set;}
    public string NSchool { get; set; }
    public int NSchoolDist { get; set; }
    public int NCrime { get; set; } 
}
```

FYI: if you might be able to use a Repeater instead of programmably creating html (http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp), although I don't know if it fits your use case.

Edit: also if you are the one creating the source files then consider deserialization from xml.

Comment: I'm actually scraping the data from a website collecting information totally unrelated to housing. I used housing in place of statistics from an online game just to generalize things a bit more. I ended up taking your approach as it suited my needs the best in this case! Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your site.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is the use case of the object? If it's simply a data transfer object then leaving it as it is should be fine. However if parts of the object are to be used throughout the application then you could break it down into pieces like so:

```
public class Downstairs : Floor
{
    public IList<Room> Rooms { get; set;}
}

public class Upstairs : Floor
{
    public IList<Room> Rooms { get;set; }
}

public class House
{
    public HouseOwner Owner { get;set; }
    public readonly IList<Floor> Floors { get; private set;}

    public House(HouseOwner owner, IList<Floor> floors)
    {
        this.Owner = owner;
        this.Floors = floors;
    }

    public void AddFloor(Floor floor)
    {
        this.Floors.Add(floor);
    }

    public int TotalFloors()
    {
        return this.Floors.Count();
    }
}
```

By modelling your data like this each object encapsulates its own and properties data making it a little more organised than a large generalised class.

Comment: Considering the schema's for both Upstairs and Downstairs are the same,  why should he have a different POCO class for each?